# Customize setting date - jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

With a datepicker like the one here: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/, I am wondering how to customize it so if a user enters the number 5 in a text box, the datepicker will automatically set the date to Today + 5. So, if you want to set the date to be 30 days into the future, you would type 30, and the datepicker would set the correct date.

I would want this functionality to be in addition to the existing and not in place of it.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Edit:

Here is an example of the datepicker I am using.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Restrict date range</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this? (done very quickly, you may need to tweak - don't rely on it 100%)

```
textboxVal = $('#textboxID').val();
var date = new Date($textboxVal);

    function formatDate() {
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1 ;
        var day = date.getDate() + textboxVal;
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        month = month < 10 ? '0' + month : month;
        day = day < 10 ? '0' + day : day;
        var strDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
        return strDate;
    }
```

Then set the value in the datepicker  to be strDate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not able to get this to work, but I am most likely doing something wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you running into issues?